# Using Scanf after getchar?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I am taking C programming course. I did not understand these codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    int ival;
    printf("type : ");
    c = getchar();
    scanf("%d", &ival);
    printf("c     = %d\n", c);  //65
    printf("ival  = %d\n", ival);  //127
    return 0;
}
```

For example whenever I type **Abc**, I am getting **c = 65**; **ival = 1**.
why ival is 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ival` is never initialized, so it can have any value. The reason is that, `c` is receiving `'A'` (through `getchar()`) and then `scanf` **fails** to read a number (since the next character in the input, `'b'`, is not a decimal number), so it never touches `ival`.

You can check the return value of `scanf` to see if it fails or succeeds:

```
if (scanf("%d", &ival) != 1)
    printf("you need to enter a number\n");
else
    printf("entered: %d\n", ival);
```

Note that `scanf` returns the number of *items* it successfully read and assigned. For example `scanf("%d %f %c", ...)` would return 3 if all three items were correctly read.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that *assigned* means that ignored input (such as those with the assignment-suppresion modifier (`*`)) doesn't count towards the return value of `scanf` (C11, 7.21.6.2.10,16). Furthermore, `%n` doesn't affect the return value of `scanf` (C11, 7.21.6.2.12).</sub>

Comment: small correction: `scanf` returns the number of items successfully matched *and* assigned. The concept is different; if you use `%*s`, this will not count towards the final return value, yet it could have read it correctly.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, you are absolutely right. I added this information.

Answer (score 2):

With `Abc`, `getchar()` will read `A`, thus, `c` will hold the character code for `A`, which happens to be 65 on your machine (this is the ascii code for `A`).

For `ival`, you can get anything: since `%d` on `scanf()` expects to read an integer, and you didn't provide one, `scanf()` returned prematurely, leaving `bc` in the input buffer, so the value you read from `ival` when you call `printf()` is undefined: it can print anything.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your program invokes **undefined behavior**.`A` is read by `getchar` while `bc` is left unread by `scanf` because `%d` expects to read an integer and hence on encountering the character it stop reading immediately and leave `ival` uninitialized.